# Calling SP 2013 workflow not resuming after completion of called SP 2010 workflow

Tags: designer-workflow

I have tried to call SP 2010 workflow from SP 2013 workflow using "Start a workflow" Action.
But, called SP 2010 workflow not returned to master SP 2013 workflow after completion.
why this happened??
please help me with it.

Updated Details: 
Parent SP 2013 workflow calls the child SP 2010 workflow. then SP 2010 workflow completes its functionality properly. After that SP 2010 workflow supposed to return to the Parent SP 2013 workflow. But, it is not returning to parent workflow, instead it gets stuck after execution.

Comment: You need to give further details. Is there an error or something shown? Has it worked before? Try to detail the question more.

Comment: No, there was not any error. and yes, it was worked before sometimes. but, now it is not working.

Comment: Parent SP 2013 workflow calls the child SP 2010 workflow. then SP 2010 workflow completes its functionality properly.
After that SP 2010 workflow supposed to return to the Parent SP 2013 workflow.
But, it is not returning to parent workflow, instead it gets stuck after execution.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I'm afraid I can't come up with an ambiguous solutions right now. Though, you should edit the details you added in the comments to your original question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old but hopefully it can help. I was running into this problem too. I had the action to start a 2010 workflow and in the properties it was supposed to wait. But it never woke back up after finishing. This seems to be a bug because from the documentation this is supposed to work, that is why there is the wait option. 
So I hacked a workaround:

- Set the Start List workflow properties to NOT wait (drop down next to the start 2010 workflow action -> properties)
- Created a field on the list called Resume Workflow
- Created another field called sub workflow status (my 2010 is an approval workflow and i need to know if it was approved/rejected, this could be for any info you need back from your 2010 workflow.)
- Before my call to start 2010 workflow I set Resume workflow = No
- Inside my 2010 workflow, when it is done i set the sub workflow status and Resume Workflow = Yes
- In my 2013 workflow, after the call to start the 2010 workflow I add a Wait for field to change action, looking for Resume Workflow = Yes

I've basically moved the wait from the start workflow action and made my own. And because we aren't waiting on the actual workflow action then we can't trust the data in the local variable for that 2010 workflow so we have to store the information in our own location.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the 2010 Workflow treats the field differently and it only seems to work in 2010...it takes the ID and tags it (single) with **;#**.  If you put a singular lookup value in the record, then in a workflow call that record (lookup as ID's), it shows up as:
**ID;#**
so when you build a value set in your 2010 Workflow, you do it with a variable string like this

If **ItemCount** is greater than **0**

set **WorkflowVariableMultiValueItem** to

**[%ItemMultiID1%:];#**

If **ItemCount** is greater than **1**

set **WorkflowVariableMultiValueItem** to

**[%Variable: WorkflowVariableMultiValueItem%];#[%ItemMultiID2%:];#**

If **ItemCount** is greater than **2**

set **WorkflowVariableMultiValueItem** to

**[%Variable: WorkflowVariableMultiValueItem%];#[%ItemMultiID3%:];#**

and so on, as long as the string ends with **;#** it should work, then you can call the 2010 workflow from the 2013 workflow:

Then start **2010Workflow** with **no parameters** on **CurrentItem**(Output to Data source)